# Divide xml using spring batch into small xmls

Tags: spring-batch

I have to read a huge 5 GB xml file like below using spring batch and divide it into separate xml files for each record in below xml. These xml files will be sent to jms queue as writer. Is there any way in spring batch to read xml and divide it in multiple xmls based on  tags. ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <record refId="1001">
        <name>abc</name>
        <age>31</age>
        <dob>31/8/1982</dob>
        <income>200,000</income>
    </record>
    <record refId="1002">
        <name>xyz</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <dob>26/7/1983</dob>
        <income>100,999</income>
    </record>
    <record refId="1003">
        <name>pqr</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <dob>21/8/1984</dob>
        <income>1,000,000</income>
    </record>
    <record refId="1004">
        <name>leeyy</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <dob>21/3/1984</dob>
        <income>80,000.89</income>
    </record>
</company>
```

Comment: `divide it into separate xml files for each record`: Just to make sure I understand your question, you want to split the 5gb file into separate files where each file contains a single `record` tag? So if the input file has 1 million tags you want to have 1 million files, is that correct? `These xml files will be sent to jms queue as writer`: Does this mean you are trying to proceed in tow steps?

Comment: Is it required that the JMS message payload be an xml file instead of a serialized object representing a `record` tag? Because otherwise you can use a single chunk-oriented step with a `StaxEventItemReader` and a `JmsItemWriter`.This avoids splitting the file.

Comment: yes you are correct but instead of files it can be String object of record which can be put on queue. Cant use JmsItemWriter as we have our own JMSPublisher with authentication it can be called from customItemWriter. Just want to know how to divide that file into small String objects of XML as string while reading. Is there any such reader available in Spring. Writer will be custom.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description + comments, I see no need to split the file into multiple xml files and then read those xml files to send them as messages to the JMS queue.

You can create a POJO representing a `record` tag and use a chunk-oriented step with a `StaxEventItemReader<Record>` and your custom writer.